# Not able to install "cloud-object-storage" cli on docker container

Tags: ibm-cloud, object-storage

```
[root@94889d71399b ~]# ibmcloud plugin install cloud-object-storage
Installing binary...
FAILED
Unable to obtain plug-in's metadata. Error: exit status 2

Tried to directly download bin and execute it.
Downloaded bin from repo link:-
```

*https://plugins.ng.bluemix.net/downloads/bluemix-plugins/cloud-object-storage/0.2.0/cloud-object-storage-linux-amd64-0.2.0*

After changing permission of bin executed it and got below error:-

    *panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
    [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x40 pc=0x77b34a]*

```
goroutine 1 [running]:
github.ibm.com/objectstore/bluemix-cos-cli/vendor/github.ibm.com/objectstore/cos-go-sdk/aws/credentials.parseJSON(0xa660a1, 0x15, 0xa5f600, 0x8, 0x0, 0x0)
        /Users/WBHuber/go/src/github.ibm.com/objectstore/bluemix-cos-cli/vendor/github.ibm.com/objectstore/cos-go-sdk/aws/credentials/credentials.go:248 +0x2a
github.ibm.com/objectstore/bluemix-cos-cli/vendor/github.ibm.com/objectstore/cos-go-sdk/aws/credentials.GetToken(0xa662ed, 0x15)
        /Users/WBHuber/go/src/github.ibm.com/objectstore/bluemix-cos-cli/vendor/github.ibm.com/objectstore/cos-go-sdk/aws/credentials/credentials.go:261 +0x4b

My OS version details are:-
[root@94889d71399b ~]# uname -r
3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64
[root@94889d71399b ~]# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"`enter code here`
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
```